# Write mouse coordinates and mouse clicks with timestamps to file?

Tags: linux, bash, mouse, xinput

I'm trying to create a bash script that records the location of the mouse every 5 milliseconds. I also want to record the timestamps and locations of mouse-clicks.

Recording the mouse location has been easy with `xdotool getmouselocation`. I've been able to record mouse clicks using some of the suggestions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command
However, I've not been able to combine the two.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote, so that we can see where you get stuck?

Comment: Doing this 200 times a second in a scripting language is going to trash performance

Comment: What would be a better alternative to a scripting language? I stayed away from higher lever languages like Java because I wasn't sure if these languages would have access to mouse information if running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accepted answer of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command have an example to get mouse status change. With little modification you get print the mouse location upon mouse button down.

@Gem Taylor mentioned using script language for this is not an optional way.

During test run, I experienced cases when clicks are not get captured.

```
#!/bin/bash

MOUSE_ID=$(xinput --list | grep -i -m 1 'mouse' | grep -o 'id=[0-9]\+' | grep -o '[0-9]\+')

STATE1=$(xinput --query-state $MOUSE_ID | grep 'button\['"."'\]=down' | sort)
while true; do
        sleep 0.005
        STATE2=$(xinput --query-state $MOUSE_ID | grep 'button\['"."'\]=down' | sort)
        CLICK=$(comm -13 <(echo "$STATE1") <(echo "$STATE2"))
        if [[ -n $CLICK ]]; then
                echo "$CLICK"
                xinput --query-state $MOUSE_ID | grep 'valuator\['
        fi
        STATE1=$STATE2
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get this code to work earlier because the correct MOUSE_ID did not have 'mouse' in the name.